# Mikrotik: Add HTTP Header Parameter to Requests

Tags: http-headers, mikrotik, request

I want to add a parameter of MikroTik to all HTTP header requests using MikroTik. So all client and servers that connected to the MikroTik can trace the parameter in their HTTP header.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot manipulate the HTTP headers with Mikrotik.

You need a reverse proxy like HAProxy or Nginx to achieve this.

**Update:**
Here I describe a solution on how you can add Nginx or HAProxy support on Mikrotik
[NAT to two different servers on the same port via hostname with Mikrotik RB2011](https://serverfault.com/questions/654716/nat-to-two-different-servers-on-the-same-port-via-hostname-with-mikrotik-rb2011/656070#656070)